# Keep on getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1, 7'

Tags: python, arrays, list, valueerror

I'm attempting to make a hangman like game, but when I run this code I currently have, I keep on getting errors, I've tried making new variables such as int1 and int2 but to no avail. Here is the code:

```
from nltk.corpus import words
import random

word_list = words.words()
password = random.choice(word_list)
finish = len(password)

print("The password has", len(password),"letters")
print(password)

while finish > 0:
    
    guess = input("Please enter a letter to see where it is in the word:  ")
    occur = password.count(guess)
    
    mylist = {', '.join([str(i) for i, c in enumerate(password) if c == guess])}
    print(mylist)

    int1 = [int(y) for y in mylist]

    int2 = [x+1 for x in mylist]
    print(ints)

    if len(guess) > 1 or len(guess) < 1:
        print("Enter 1 standard keyboard letter to see if it is in the word")
    
    elif guess in password:
         print(f"This letter is at position {', '.join([str(i) for i, c in enumerate(password) if c == guess])} in the word")
         finish = finish - occur
         password = password.replace(guess,'.')
         print("Only", finish, "letters left to guess")
         
    else:
        print("Try again")
```

What I want line 16-22 to do is first convert the elements of the list from string to integer, then print out the list, and then print out the same list again but with 1 added to every single element of the list.
Here is the error I keep on getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ARR2K18/Desktop/Hangman.py", line 29, in <module>
    int1 = [int(y) for y in mylist]
  File "/Users/ARR2K18/Desktop/Hangman.py", line 29, in <listcomp>
    int1 = [int(y) for y in mylist]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1, 7'
```

Would like some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
mylist = {', '.join([...])}
print(mylist)

int1 = [int(y) for y in mylist]
```

The `', '.join(...)` is going to give you a result like "1, 7", and the set will look something like `{"1, 7", "3, 4", ... }`. Then when you call `int()` on one of those set elements you get the error shown.

The fix for this is probably to simply drop the `join` call and use the list comprehension alone.

Comment: Probably true, but the OP's code has multiple issues. `int1` and `int2` are calculated and never used (and the calculation of `int2` will also break if the list elements are strings). Then there is attempt to print `ints` but it was never defined. And the line number in the error message doesn't tally with the code in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I sort of ignored the line numbers since I assumed they were off.  And there are definitely other issues, but this *should* address the error he cited.